# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error using Apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, http-headers

I know this is duplicate issue...I got to know that I have to change below tag

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But I am wondering where can I find the file .htaccess file ..I am unable to locate this..

I have developed rest services but which is not accessible through UI 
Can anybody guide me the location where i have to change the tag so that it will not give any error

Comment: Are we talking about Tomcat or Apache webserver?